# Create sentences with markov chain in python

Tags: python, markov-chains

I have a Python code that uses markov chains to generate sentences, but for the code works I have to define 2 starting words, but I want that the first word was randomly chosen.

this is the code:

```
import random

def getLines(filename):
 return [line[0:-1] for line in open(filename).readlines()]

def getWords(lines):
 words = []
 for line in lines:
  words.extend(line.split())
 return words

def createProbabilityHash(words):
 numWords = len(words)
 wordCount = {}
 for word in words:
  if wordCount.has_key(word):
   wordCount[word] += 1
  else:
   wordCount[word] = 1

 for word in wordCount.keys():
  wordCount[word] /= 1.0 * numWords
 return wordCount

def getRandomWord(wordCount):
 randomValue = random.random()
 cumulative = 0.0
 choosenWord = ""
 print wordCount
 for word in wordCount:
  probability = wordCount[word]
  if probability > cumulative:
      cumulative = probability
      choosenWord = word

 return choosenWord


words = getWords(getLines("frases.txt"))
wordMap = {}
previous = (words[0], words[1])
for word in words[2:]:
 if wordMap.has_key(previous):
  wordMap[previous].append(word)
 else:
  wordMap[previous] = [word]
 previous = (previous[1], word)

for word in wordMap.keys():
 probabilityHash = createProbabilityHash(wordMap[word])

 wordMap[word] = probabilityHash

palavras = ['hello', 'apple', 'something', 'yeah', 'nope', 'lalala']
previous = (".", "A") #Starting words
numWords = 10 # The number of words to print

print previous[0], previous[1],
for i in range(numWords):
 word = getRandomWord(wordMap[previous])
 print word,
 if word.endswith(","):
  print "\n"
 if word.endswith("."):
  break

 previous = (previous[1], word)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will choose at random from the words in your dictionary:

```
import random
previous[0] = random.choice(wordMap.keys())
```

Comment: thank you, but i put that and give me this error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gerson\Desktop\test2.py", line 56, in <module>
    previous[0] = random.choice(wordMap.keys())
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: i already import the random function in the top of the code, i think that's not the problem.

Comment: sorry, you can't overwrite an individual element in a tuple.  Using intermediary variables: `first = random.choice(wordMap.keys())` then assign whatever the second word is to `second` and set `previous = (first, second)`.

Comment: thank you, now the first word is randomly chosen, but i forgot one thing, the words cannot be so "randomly" because I need the first word random chosen from the first word off each line in my dictionary, understand, I was clear? if you see my code I already do this `numWords = len(words)`